# Redirect to crontab with an heredocument

Tags: cron, io-redirection, here-document

Is it possible to print to `crontab` with an heredocument?

I tried these but failed:

```
cat <<-"CRONTAB" > crontab
    0 0 * * * cat /dev/null > /var/mail/root
    0 1 * * 0 certbot renew -q
CRONTAB
```

and:

```
bash <<-"CRONTAB" > crontab
    0 0 * * * cat /dev/null > /var/mail/root
    0 1 * * 0 certbot renew -q
CRONTAB
```

This on the other hand is not an heredocument, but worked:

```
# CRONTAB
echo "
    0 0 * * * cat /dev/null > /var/mail/root
    0 1 * * 0 certbot renew -q
" | crontab
```

I thus wonder if it's even possible with heredocument.

Comment: `> crontab` is a *file* redirection - not the same as `| crontab`

Comment: You *could* just define the job in a new file in `/etc/cron.d`.  Might be simpler.

Comment: @steeldriver how do you define `| crontab`?

Comment: I think @steeldriver is pointing out that `crontab` is a *command.*  On some distros the crontab *file* may also be named "crontab," but at least on RHEL it is not.  (It's called `/var/spool/cron/$USER`.)

Comment: @Wildcard yes sorry if I wasn't very clear - I meant that the OP's first two snippets create a (likely local) file named `crontab` whereas the third pipes the content to the `crontab` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `crontab` is a command, so all you need to do is feed it the heredoc:

```
crontab <<-"CRONTAB"
```

But as has been mentioned before, it’s an awful lot easier to manage cron jobs by manipulating files in `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.d` etc.

Comment: Especially if you don't want to clobber any cronjobs that may have already been defined!